# .htaccess in subdirectory of default apache2 directory

Tags: apache2

I have apache2 installed and running on my computer, and I have a folder in

```
/var/www/html/my-site
```

That I want to enable

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

So far I put a .htaccess file in the my-site folder, with

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

But I'm a little unsure where to enable .htaccess for the directory. I made sure the apache2 header module is loaded, and I put a new directory listing in my apache2.conf file as such (unsure if that will work?), which still does not make it work:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/my-site>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I don't want to mess around with adding a new site and possibly doing reverse proxy, so I just wanted to be able to make this site work. Is it possible, and am I doing something wrong here?

Finally, I'm trying to use the javascript lib axios and run a request cross domain, but I get the error which is the reason why I'm doing this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sitethatisdesired.com. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the "IfModule" works in htaccess. Put the `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in your vhost.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where in which file would that be exactly?

Comment: The same file in which you put the `Directory`. And Restart/reload after changes

Comment: That's the main apache2.conf file though, and I would prefer not to enable access control for * from everywhere, rather just for that specific sub directory. I tried to remove "IfModule" from the .htaccess and just leave the Header lines, but still that didn't work. Would there be a simple way to check if .htaccess is read properly?

Comment: You can add custom vhost files. Normally in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and after that `a2ensite enable myvhost.con` and restart

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid if you read my original question, but if it can't be done I guess it can't be done

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"                  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
</IfModule>
```

you forget the `:`

Comment: Unfortunately even after correcting this alleged typo it is not working.

Comment: Ok, sry then I have no better idea. I work normally with own vhosts.